# How to tell Python to prefer module from $HOME/lib/python over /usr/lib/python?

Tags: python, module

In Python, I'm getting an error because it's loading a module from `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages` but I'd like it to use my version in `$HOME/python-modules/lib/python2.6/site-packages`, which I installed using `pip-python --install-option="--prefix=$HOME/python-modules --ignore-installed`

How can I tell Python to use my version of the library? Setting `PYTHONPATH` to `$HOME/python-modules/lib/python2.6/site-packages` doesn't help, since `/usr/lib/...` apparently has precedence.

Comment: have you tried just prepending the path to your version of the library before the import? i.e. `import sys; sys.path.insert(0,"/path/to/your/version"); import something`

Comment: I have never done this my self, but I think you could use imp.find_module() and imp.load_module(). [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at the [site](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) module for ways to customize your environment.

One way to accomplish this is to add a file to a location currently on `sys.path` called `usercustomize.py`, when Python is starting up it will automatically import this file, and you can use it to modify `sys.path`.

First, set `$PYTHONPATH` to `$HOME` (or add `$HOME` if `$PYTHONPATH` has a value), then create the file `$HOME/usercustomize.py` with the following contents:

```
import sys, os
my_site = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'],
                       'python-modules/lib/python2.6/site-packages')
sys.path.insert(0, my_site)
```

Now when you start Python you should see your custom site-packages directory before the system default on `sys.path`.

Answer (score 9):

Newer Python versions now have built-in support to search the opendesktop location:

```
$HOME/.local/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages
```

If you put your local modules there you don't have to any sys.path manipulations.

Answer (score 4):

If one has multiple versions of a package installed, say e.g. SciPy:

```
>>> import scipy; print(scipy.__version__); print(scipy.__file__)
0.17.0
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py
```

and one would like the user installed version (installed e.g. using `pip install --user --upgrade scipy`) to be prefered, one needs a [usercustomize.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#module-site) file in `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/` with e.g. this content:

```
import sys, os
my_site = os.path.join(
    os.environ['HOME'], '.local/lib/python%d.%d/site-packages' % (
        sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1]))
for idx, pth in enumerate(sys.path):
    if pth.startswith('/usr'):
        sys.path.insert(idx, my_site)
        break
else:
    raise ValueError("No path starting with /usr in sys.path")
```

(the for loop selecting index ensures that packages installed in "develop mode" takes precedence) now we get our user specific version of SciPy:

```
>>> import scipy; print(scipy.__version__); print(scipy.__file__)
0.18.1
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

to prefer packages installed to userbase (e.g. `pip install --user --upgrade cool_thing` )

in `~/.bashrc`,`~/.profile`, or whatever the init file for your shell is, add

```
export PYTHONUSERBASE="$HOME/python-modules"
```

in `$PYTHONUSERBASE/usercustomize.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, site
sys.path.insert(0, site.getusersitepackages())
```

Comment: I think the correct location for the file is `$PYTHONUSERBASE/lib/pythonX.X/site-packages/usercustomize.py`