# Load user python package in preference to system

Tags: python, package

If I have a package installed under ~/.local that is also installed in the system python how do i load the user package in preference?

Specifically I want to use my own distutils...

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9934919/how-to-tell-python-to-prefer-module-from-home-lib-python-over-usr-lib-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a file `~/.local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/usercustomize.py` with the following contents.

```
import sys
import os

PYVER = sys.version_info
PATH = os.path.join(os.environ["HOME"], ".local", "lib", "python%d.%d" % (PYVER.major, PYVER.minor))

sys.path.insert(0, PATH)
```

That will insert your $HOME/.local/lib/pythonX.X to be searched before the system one. Then you put your custom modules in there. They will be found before the "stock" ones.

You may have to change the "lib" to "lib64", depends on your system.

Comment: You wouldn't have to change lib to lib64.  In fact, you could change it to lib16 and it would still work.  sys.path really doesn't care about what directory you put in there, as long as it contains importable modules.

Comment: @ThomasVanderStichele IN order to find the initial usercustomize module it is placed in the user's private directory, which is added by Python itself. My python adds this: `/home/keith/.local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages`, it has the "lib64" in it. If you make a directory with just "lib" then Python wouldn't find it and this won't work. The one you add could be anythinng, but since it goes in the same base path the path name should be the same, since it won't exist and would then require the extra step of creating it.

Comment: But your explanation mentions lib64 while your code says lib... you'd still have to create the dirs.  And I think it would be mighty confusing to put a path at the front that's (if I follow you correctly already in sys.path - makes more sense to use a non-existing path to add to begin with.  Just my 2c

Comment: @ThomasVanderStichele I changed one but not the other, an oversight. But python's cached byte-compiled code is version specific so it's usually placed in a versioned directory, and here I put it in a place that is named consistently with the usual Python convention. The path in the front is not already on sys.path, only the subdirectory "site-packages" is. And that one is after the base system one. The OP wanted something before, so this inserts a new one before. You're right it could cause confusion, but I am assuming the OP is prepared to deal with that.

Comment: Only works for me -- if I also add `"site-packages"` in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You add your path to the front of sys.path:

```
  sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/.local')
```